# quickfix session config issues

Tags: session, config, quickfix

I've compiled and trolled around the quickfix ( http://www.quickfixengine.org ) source and the examples. I figured a good starting point would be to compile (C++) and run the 'executor' example, then use the 'tradeclient' example to connect to 'executor', and send it order requests.
I created two seperate session files one for the 'executor' as an acceptor, and one for the 'tradeclient' as the initiator. They're both running on the same Win7 pc.

'executor' runs, but tradeclient can't connect to it, and I can't figure out why. I downloaded Mini-fix and was able to send messages to executor, so I know that executor is working. I figure that the problem is with the tradeclient session settings. I've included both of them below, I was hoping someone could point out what's causing them to not communicate. They're both running on the same computer using port 56156.

--accceptor session.txt----

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=acceptor
ReconnectInterval=5
SenderCompID=EXEC
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
TargetCompID=SENDER
HeartBtInt=5
#SocketConnectPort=
SocketAcceptPort=56156
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
TransportDataDictionary=pathToXml/spec/FIX50.xml
StartTime=07:00:00
EndTime=23:00:00
FileStorePath=store
```

---- initiator session.txt ---

```
[DEFAULT]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=5
SenderCompID=SENDER
DefaultApplVerID=FIX.5.0

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIXT.1.1
TargetCompID=EXEC
HeartBtInt=5
SocketConnectPort=56156
#SocketAcceptPort=56156
SocketConnectHost=127.0.0.1
TransportDataDictionary=pathToXml/spec/FIX50.xml
StartTime=07:00:00
EndTime=23:00:00
FileLogPath=log
FileStorePath=store
```

--------end------

Update: Thanks for the resonses... Turns out that my logfile directories didn't exist. Once I created them, they both started communicating. Must have been some logging error that didn't throw an exception, but disabled proper behavior.

Is there an error condition that I should be checking? I was relying on exceptions, but that's obviously not enough.

Comment: Can you provide the log from the connector

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be config, check that your message sequence numbers are in synch, especially since you've been connecting to a different server using the same settings.

Comment: Where do I set/reset those sequence numbers? Don't they get reset when I kill/restart the acceptor server? Or does that live in some logfile?

Comment: they are in the SeqNums file, just delete it to reset. They have to persist sequence numbers because some counterparties (most from my experience) persist sequence numbers.

Comment: also look at this http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html#Session the bottom of this section shows how to set the sessions to reset the sequence numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `TargetCompID` and `SenderCompID` on the acceptor to `*`

Comment: I tried that and got the following:  "Configuration failed: Could not open body file: store\FIXT.1.1-\*-\*.body". I think the \* can't be used as part of a filename in the message store.

Comment: I have no problem with that on my acceptor settings.  I am not using FIXT1.1 though, but I doubt that has anything to do with it.

Comment: which FIX version you are using